# Google Action - Migration from one Google account to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-account

I want to migrate my Google action project from one Google account to another.
However, I am not part of any organization hence the migration option on Google cloud for my project doesn't work.
Can anyone help me understand how we can migrate the Google action with no organization from one google account to another google account without any organization created on Google cloud console?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to migrate a project from non-org to another account (non-org). Have you looked at the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

Answer (score 0):

**To migrate your GCP project, follow these steps:**

1. Navigate to google cloud console
2. Select the source account where you want to migrate project from
3. In the navigation menu select "IAM"
4. At the top, click "ADD"
5. Add the destination account using Permissions/Add Member/Is Owner
6. Accept the Invitation from destination account
7. If you want to remove ownership of the source account, on the destination account, go back to the IAM section and delete your account from the list.

Refer [granting access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console) for information.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked the same at my end. Although the approach work to ownership transfer I still see the project for the same in my account. I want to completely migrate the project also to the new account.

Comment: Though visible, the source account has no access to modify any GCP resources.

Comment: The source account does have access to modify the resources as the source account is the owner of the project. I tested the scenario. Also for me, the skill needs to migrate to a new organization, therefore, I need the complete transfer of the project and skill to another account.

Comment: You can remove ownership of the source account from the destination account, go to the IAM section in the destination account and delete your source account from the list.